# How do i display an image when a variable reach a certain value?

Tags: javascript, image, if-statement

So far i have made it so that when the variable "poeng" reaches a value over 12 it shows the message "Hello World", but what if i want it to display an image?

The HTML

5

7

+5

The coding (javascript)

```
var poeng = 0;


function myFunction() {

poeng = 5;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function myFunction2() {

poeng = 7;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function myFunction3() {

poeng = poeng + 5;

console.log(poeng)
check()
}

function check() {
 if(poeng > 12) {

  console.log("Hello World");

//here i want it to display an image

 }
}
```

Comment: Unhide an HTML element? Create and append an HTML element to the page? There are many ways this could be implemented.

Comment: You have to create the Image element (see `document.createElemen()` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)), set its attributes and append it to the DOM (see `ParentNode.append()` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display an image instead of just outputting to the console, you have to create an `<img>` element, add it's `alt` and `src` attributes and then append it to an element inside your page.

Here's an example. The image is created with a little helper function and appended to the `<body>` element inside the `check()` function:

```
var poeng = 0;
var imgURL = 'https://fillmurray.com/1000/645'; // <-- URL of the image, using a placeholder service for now


// --- Image creation helper
function createImage(url) {
  var imgEl = document.createElement('img'); // <-- create an <img> node/element
  imgEl.alt = '';                            // <-- add an alt-attribute
  imgEl.src = url;                           // <-- add it's source
  return imgEl;                              // <-- return the <img> to the caller
}


function myFunction() {
  // ... elided for brevity ...
}

function myFunction2() {
  // ... elided for brevity ...
}

function myFunction3() {
  // ... elided for brevity ...
}

function check() {
  if(poeng > 12) {
    console.log("Hello World");
    //here i want it to display an image

    var imgEl = createImage(imgURL);         // <-- create the <img>
    document.body.appendChild(imgEl);        // <-- add it to the <body> element
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you David! I am really new to Javascript so it is nice that people like you are kind enough to help me with stuff like this.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace your console with any of the as listed above. Here is an example for a div with an id of image:

```
$('#image').html('<img src="url" />');
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants a solution _without_ using jQuery.